How to stem a country's name and adjective to the same root
I wrote an application that uses the Porter stemming algorithm to index text. I was surprised to learn that the algorithm does not stem a country's name to the same root as a country's adjective. For example the algorithm does not stem the word "American" to "America". Also the algorithm does not stem "runner" to "run". The same results occur if my program uses the Snowball algorithm.
Is there a stemming algorithm that would stem the above examples closer to what I was expecting? Can my program use a large language model for better results?

Stemming isn’t really intended to handle transformations like "America" to "American" (or vice versa), because they don’t share a common morphological root. Stemming generally aims to reduce inflected forms of a word to a base form (e.g., "running" to "run"), focusing on suffix-stripping rather than transforming between nouns and adjectives.
I created a script and achieved the same results with Porter Stemming as you find. However, using Lancaster stemming from NLTK I achieved Runner --> Run
